# Calling Template method from different class.

Tags: c++, templates, csv, methods, stream

I have a template method  that overloads the operator <<. I need To call that operator when a method from a class is called. But when I try it gives me some compiling errors.

This is the method from the concrete Class Named BTreeLeave

```
 bool BTreeLeave::burn() {
    csv::WriterStream os("products.txt", std::ios_base::out);
    os.set_delimiter(',');
    if (os.is_open()) {

        os << 1693 << NEWLINE;
        os << 15 << 16 << 17 << 20 << NEWLINE;
        os << "s" << "i" << "f" << NEWLINE;
        os << 2 << NEWLINE;
        os << "+" << NEWLINE;
        os << "0" << NEWLINE;
    }
```

The Template function is this one

```
template<typename T>
typename csv::WriterStream& operator << (typename csv::WriterStream& ostm, const T& val)
{    
    if(!ostm.get_after_newline())
        ostm.get_ofstream() << ostm.get_delimiter();    
    ostm.get_ofstream() << val;    
    ostm.set_after_newline(false);    
    return ostm;
}
template<>
inline csv::WriterStream& operator << (typename csv::WriterStream& ostm, const char& val)
{
    if(val==NEWLINE)
    {
        ostm.get_ofstream() << NEWLINE;
            ostm.set_after_newline(true);
    }    
    else
        ostm.get_ofstream() << val;    
    return ostm;
}
```

The Error I get is
‘csv::WriterStream’ is not derived from ‘std::basic_ostream’
and 
"no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘csv::WriterStream’ and ‘int’)"

If I try to call the << operator from the main Function is does Work. What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Where do you have your output operator overloads defined? They are in the global scope? Not in any class or namespace? Can you perhaps please try and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us?

Answer (score 0):

do you try below defination

```
template<typename T>
typename csv::WriterStream& operator << (typename csv::WriterStream& ostm,  T val)
{    
    if(!ostm.get_after_newline())
        ostm.get_ofstream() << ostm.get_delimiter();    
    ostm.get_ofstream() << val;    
    ostm.set_after_newline(false);    
    return ostm;
}
```